# Is icmp blocked at travis-ci?

Tags: travis-ci

I have a

```
ping -c 1 -q n.n.n.n command
```

that fails only at Travis CI.

Is ping blocked there?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my own question, straight from travis support

> Hi Name,
>
> Thanks for writing in. Yes indeed, on our container based
>   infrastructure, ICMP is not possible. Could you speficy `sudo:
>   required` in the .travis.yml and see if it brings improvement?
>
> Thanks!
>
> Joep